# Functions in R - clarification

Tags: r

I have a csv file with 50 variables. I want a function that allows the user to enter a two digit state code, then returns the list of major cities in that state.
Let's say the variables in question are called "city" and "state", and the file is called "state-data.csv".

How do I write a function to do this where the output would look something like the following:

```
mystate("VA")

VA  "Richmond" "Charlottesville" "Alexandria" ...
```

Note: the format of the output is not important, only that the function works as intended.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my first contribution, and keep in mind that I'm still learning R too :) . 
I'm assuming that your data frame is formed from a bunch of different columns among which "state" and city exist. I'm gonna call that data frame my_df.

you can try the following:

```
my_df[my_df$state=='VA',"city"]
```

or as a function:

```
mystate <- function(st){    
    log <- my_df$state==st
    return(my_df[log,"city"])
}
```

Hopefully this will help.

Comment: Yes, that worked beautifully. Thank you so much. I am struggling tremendously with applying "If then else" statements or "loops" and writing functions to a single file or multiple files. I just don't understand it and haven't found a tutorial that helps. I will dissect and ponder your code a while until it all makes sense.

Comment: Here's some clarifications on how it works:
you have your data frame in a tabular format which has "state", "city",...etc. What you want, is to select the cities of a given state. 
The first thing to do, is to point on the "state" column.
By typing "my_df$state=='VA'", you tell R: take the column "state" of the "my_df" data frame, and look for the rows of that column that match "VA". R start looking over each row of the "state" column. If "VA" exists, then R interpret it as a TRUE, otherwise it's a FALSE(To check it type only "my_df$state=='VA'", and you will see that).

Comment: Next, and as a reminder, logical vectors are one way to select the rows of a data frame.

Comment: Now,lets go back my_df[my_df$state=='VA',]: from the first part, we have a logical vector, that goes over all the rows of the entire data frame. We use to select the lines we want, and for the columns all of them are selected. Which means a data frame with 50 variables, but has a state only of VA. All we need now, is to tell R, from that previous data frame, select the variable called "city". That's why we added the "city" in the **** of my_df[my_df$state=='VA',***]. So we typed, my_df[my_df$state=='VA',"city"].

Hopefully it's not confusing.